# select query based on time part of the datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012. I have a large table (call it `temperatures`). The table contains minute data over the past x number of years of recorded temperatures. Table contains approx 5 million records.

Currently I select a subset of the table with a simple query like below.

```
select t_datetime, temp_c from temperatures
where t_datetime >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
and t_datetime <= '2011-12-01 18:00:00'
order by t_datetime
```

What I would like to do is to select every temperature between two time periods but only at a certain time. For example I want the temperature at 6pm every day between 1 Jan 2010 and 1st Dec 2011. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select t_datetime, temp_c from temperatures
 where t_datetime >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00'
 and t_datetime <= '2011-12-01 18:00:00'
 and LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), t_datetime, 100), 7))='6:00PM'
 order by t_datetime
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server and that doesn't recognise DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: sorry about that. updated it now. Oh you already marked it. :P